# Control middle value colours with scale_colour_continuous using R/ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have a set of data and would like to map the `colour` aesthetic around a sort of "reference value" like so:

- values below are red
- values near are blue
- values above are green

I still want to show the fact that values are on a continuoum, so simply using a function like `cut()` and using `scale_colour_discrete` is  not what I'm looking for. Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)
y <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)
test <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
test$colour <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)
ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour)) + geom_point(size = 3)
```

That produces the following:

[image]

I'm familiar with `scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")`, however I was hoping to more deliberately transition my colours along desired value mapping to make the regions "pop" a bit more visually. Spacing would not necessarily be linear. in other words, for a reference value of 3, the mapping would be something like this:

```
value:  1     3      10
colour: red   blue   green
```

Is this possible? I'd also take alternative solutions to accomplish a good visualization to highlight "desirable" values easily among a sea of points. For example, I considered replacing values near the reference such that `(ref - tol < colour < ref + tol) <- NA`, and then using `scale_colour_gradient`'s option for `na.value`.

Or should I truly be considering the `cut()` option, just with a very small cut size and then figure out how to gradually change the colours along the resultant breaks?

Answer (score 5):

From http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/scale_gradient2.html:

```
scale_color_gradient2(low = "red", midpoint = 3, mid = "blue", high = "green")
```

UPDATE:

Concerning OP's comment - playing around with midpoints and `space="Lab"` helps:

```
# Using the Lab colour space also improves perceptual properties
# at the price of slightly slower operation
d + scale_colour_gradient2(space="Lab")
```

Back from the graveyard - given the newest comment I realized that one should put the two lines of code together:

```
scale_color_gradient2(low = "red",
midpoint = 3,
mid = "blue",
high = "green",
space="Lab")
```

Comment: Sonuva! How did I miss that scale type entirely!? One issue is that it appears it doesn't *quite* work as advertised. When I apply it to the data above, I don't get any red, presumably because the low values near 1 are too close to my "midpoint" of 3.

Comment: Yes I noticed that as well but if you move the midpoint to 5 it works. better. I guess this scale to some extent asserts uniformly distributed values across the scale.

Comment: does not seem to work at all, it is completely ignored. `scale_fill_gradient` works but is not the solution to this problem. I am using `ggplot2` version 2.2.1, maybe this feature has been deprecated?

Comment: `ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "red", midpoint = 3, 
                        mid = "blue", high = "green", 
                        space="Lab")` still looks ok with the current ggplot2 I think. What I do see is that my old answer seems to be evaluated differently in the sense that the two `scale_colour_gradient2` calls have to be combined.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to define three or more colours and to specify how the data values map to the colour scale with `scale_colour_gradientn()`. You want to define your colours and use the `values=` option to define the mapping from data to colour.

The following would implement the three-colour scheme that you suggest:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)
y <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)
test <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
test$colour <- runif(100, min = 1, max = 10)
test.plot <- ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("red","blue","green"),
                         values=rescale(c(1,3,10)), 
                         space = "Lab")
test.plot
```

This produces a graph [as illustrated here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12616850/SESO/ggplot2_gradientn_test.png) (sorry; I don't have the reputation points to embed the image).

Regarding the second part of your question, to highlight specific values, one option is to re-plot in a different colour. Going back to your original plot with the dark- to light-blue colour gradient, we can replot points near a colour value of 3 in red. To avoid any visual artifacts from the overlaid points, we can use differently-sized points, either by specifying `size =` or by using a larger shape via `shape =` (as is done in the qcc package).

```
test2 <- test[test$colour > 2.5 & test$colour < 3.5,]
test2.plot <- ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = colour)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 20) +
  geom_point(data = test2, aes(x = x, y = y), 
             colour = "red", size = 3, shape = 19)
test2.plot
```

Here's [the sample graph](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12616850/SESO/ggplot2_gradientn_test2.png).

Since this overplotting doesn't show up on the legend, some additional work would be needed to label the highlighted points.