# How to constrain the colorpalette in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

From the plot below, I'd like to constrain the transition from green to red (the yellow part) to be at the red line. I'd like green colors when z<1 and red when z>1, and the yellow colour to be centered on z=1.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

**Data** (just necessary to illustrate the plot)

```
x=seq(0,5,length=1e2)
y=seq(0,5,length=1e2)
#
df=expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
df$z=df$x*df$y
```

**Plot**

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x,y=y,z=z,fill=z)) +
geom_raster()+  
stat_contour(breaks=1, size=1, colour="red") +
scale_fill_gradientn (colours=colorRampPalette (c ("green", "yellow","red")) (20))
```

[image: Plot obtained from code]

Thank you for your help

Comment: scale_fill_gradient2() might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21595743/3124909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to create the plot. As @CMichael has pointed out, the function `scale_fill_gradient2` can be used. It allows the specification of a continuous colour scale based on three colours.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster() +  
  stat_contour(breaks = 1, size = 1, colour = "red") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow", high = "red", midpoint = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did the final code with a log transformation of the log: `ggplot(data=df, aes(x = xD, y = yD, z = zD, fill = zD)) +
  geom_raster() +  
  stat_contour(breaks = 1, size = 1, colour = "red") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", midpoint = log(1), mid = "yellow", high = "red",trans = "log")`